# why calling a export function return with no value

Tags: node.js

I am having this following code in notes.js

```
module.exports.addNote = () => {
    console.log('addNote');
    return 'New Note';
};
```

and the app.je

```
const notes = require('./notes.js');
var res = notes.addNote();
```

however when i start it it only display the console.log and not the return 'New Note'

```
> node app.js
addNote
```

Why is it ?

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a value. It doesn't print a value because you don't do that. If you need to output `res` then output it:

```
const notes = require('./notes.js');
var res = notes.addNote();
console.log(res);
```